# iOS iPhone Phonegap HTML App scrollbar and device width issue

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I created my first iOS 5.0 iPhone app and the app's actual size is 480 width by 320 height, which is the default size of the iPhone.

My problem is I don't want the app to allow scrollbars or what I really mean is the ability to scroll past the 320 in height which is happening.

I looked at the Safari Web Content guide [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)

I still can't seem to figure this out can anyone suggest a fix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do two things. in your css set your main wrapper to overflow:hidden;

also add this to your js onDeviceReady()

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){event.preventDefault()});
```

that will not allow any scrolling and lock the app down.

NOW if you do want to allow scrolling I suggest looking into iScroll it's really easy to set up and get working, and will give a native look and feel to the scrolling.